# How to eliminate white space on multiline attributed label?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

Plug this into your Playground and you will see that the second line of the label has a large amount of white space before it resumes the label's text (which is apparent because the attributed label has a background color). It's as if to center multiline labels, UIKit adds spaces in between the characters to make the label appear centered (edit: it only appears this way).

How can I eliminate the white space on multiline attributed labels so that the background color only applies to the characters of the string? I'm afraid the workaround will be relatively overkill.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let itemLabel = UILabel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        lbl()
    }

    func lbl() {
        itemLabel.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "the fox is foxy and likes to run fast through the forest", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.yellow, NSAttributedStringKey.backgroundColor: UIColor.black])
        itemLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
        itemLabel.textAlignment = .center
        itemLabel.numberOfLines = 2
        itemLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        itemLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        itemLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(itemLabel)
        itemLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        itemLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        itemLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -32).isActive = true
        itemLabel.sizeToFit()
    }

}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: I don't see any increased letter spacing in Xcode 9.3 (9E145). I do see the white space after the second line but that's expected, when I set background color for the whole label it correctly fills the content rectangle.

Comment: @SergiySalyuk The leading whitespace on the second line is what I want to eliminate. I know it's expected behavior but I'm exploring a workaround. I obviously don't want the background color to fill the entire label's bounds, just the string itself.

Comment: @slickdaddy This used to be a bug before then it got fixed and was working in iOS 10.3 now it is back in iOS 11.0 +

Comment: @slickdaddy I'm not sure I understand the problem. Here is the picture I see (with added 1px red layer border and orange background): https://imgur.com/a/XzTZaFW

Comment: @SergiySalyuk picture is correct. I want to eliminate all of that black empty space (whitespace) before the first word of the second line. I'm starting to suspect the workaround is overkill.

Comment: @slickdaddy But why don't use left alignment then?

Comment: @SergiySalyuk left alignment causes the same problem except that the first line will get the extraneous whitespace depending on where UIKit breaks the string.

Comment: @SergiySalyuk Align it left and use this string `"ggggg hhhh jjjjj mmmmmm okokokokok"`, same issue.

Comment: @slickdaddy Ah, so you can use hyphenation. Like 
`let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.hyphenationFactor = 1.0` And then add it to attributes.

Comment: @SergiySalyuk that's not a bad workaround, even though I really want the label to be centered. If all else fails, I think I'll use the hyphenation approach. I like your fix, thanks.